# Is input contains all numbers from 0-9 JS

Tags: javascript

Hey guys im struggling with this exercise. Im trying to check is input contains all numbers from 0-9. For example if input is "0a1b2345asd6s7e89" it should return true, "123789" it should be false. I tryed code below but i got feeling that im heading in wrong direction. Maybe regexp? Please help.

```js
const test = (input) => {
    const arrayOfNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    const inputArray = [...input]
    inputArray.every(el => {
        arrayOfNumbers.forEach(elNumber => {
            elNumber === el
        })
    })


}
```

Comment: do you mind using .include or .indexOf?

Comment: No im fine with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const test = (a, b) => a.every(el => b.includes(el))
```

Then you can use it like

```
const ax = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
var ab = "0a1b2345asd6s7e8"
test(ax,ab)
// -> false
ab = "0a1b2345asd6s7e89"
test(ax,ab)
// -> true
```

Answer (score 1):

in this solution i used `include()` and `indexOf()`

include: to verifie if test(input string) contains number from 0-9

indexoOf: to verifie if numbers are from 0-9 (ascending order)

**Solution:**

```
function Test(){
let ContAllNumber = 0; //0 = false, 1 = true

var test = "0a1b2345asd6s7e89";  
const arrayNum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
    if(test.includes(i)){
        arrayNum[i] = test.indexOf(i);
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}

for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    if(arrayNum[i] < arrayNum[i+1]){
        ContAllNumber = 1; 
    }
    else{
        ContAllNumber = 0; 
        break;
    }
}   

console.log(ContAllNumber);

//condition : contains number from 0 - 9
//example respecting condition: 0123456789, 0a1b2345asd6s7e89
//example NOT respecting condition: 7193456082 , a0s93as0j4
```

}

**Debuggin:**

(I recommend you to try it to understand code better)

```
function Test(){
let ContAllNumber = 0; //0 = false, 1 = true

var test = "0123456789";  
const arrayNum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
{
    if(test.includes(i))
    {
        arrayNum[i] = test.indexOf(i);
        console.log("number: " + i);
        console.log("position: " + arrayNum[i]);
    }
}

for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    if(arrayNum[i] < arrayNum[i+1])
    {
        ContAllNumber = 1; 
        console.log("position of number " + i + " is " + arrayNum[i] + " and position of the next number " + (i + 1) + " is " + arrayNum[i+1] + "so it's respecting condition (ok)");
        console.log("so you can return 1 (true)");
    }
    else
    {
        ContAllNumber = 0; 
        console.log("position of number " + i + " is " + arrayNum[i] + " and position of the next number " + (i + 1) + " is " + arrayNum[i+1] + "it is NOT respecting condition (NOT OK)");
        console.log("so you can return 0 (false)");
        break;
    }
}   

console.log(ContAllNumber);

//condition = contains number from 0 - 9
//example respecting condition: 0123456789, 0a1b2345asd6s7e89
//example NOT respecting condition: 7193456082 , a0s93as0j4
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `every` and `includes`:

```js
const test = input => [...Array(10).keys()].every(digit => input.includes(digit));
console.log("Expected output - true:", test("0a1b2345asd6s7e89"));
console.log("Expected output - false:", test("123789"));
```

`[...Array(10).keys()]` is an array of 0 to 9. The callback to `.every()` makes sure that the input contains each digit at least once.